# Call Multiple actions one after another in the react-redux, redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am totally new to the `react-redux`. I am using redux-thunk . Here, I have one login action. On that action I am calling an API which will give me some token, that I have to store in the state. Then immediately, after success of this action, I have to make another API request which will have this token in the header and will fetch more data. Based on this, I would like to redirect the user.

so,

```
import { generateToken } from '../APIs/login';
import HttpStatus from 'http-status-codes';
import { LOGIN_FAILED, LOGIN_SUCCESS } from '../constants/AppConstants';
import {  fetchUserJd } from './GetUserJd';
import history from '../history';

export function fetchToken(bodyjson) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        getLoginDetails(dispatch, bodyjson);
    }
}

export function getLoginDetails(dispatch, bodyjson) {
    generateToken(bodyjson)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200)
                dispatch(sendToken(response.payload))
            else
                dispatch(redirectUser(response.status));
        })
}

export function sendToken(data) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        data: data,
    }
}

export function redirectUser(data) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_FAILED,
        data: data,
    }
}
```

This is my login action.

```
import { FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS, FETCHING_DATA_FAILED,FETCHING_JOBS } from '../constants/AppConstants';
import { getUserJobs } from '../APIs/GetUserJd';
import history from '../history';

export function fetchUserJd(token) {
    console.log(token);
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchingJobDescription());
    }
};

export function getUserJd(dispatch, token) {
    getUserJobs(token)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200)
                dispatch(sendUserJd(response.payload))
            else
                dispatch(fetchFailure(response.status));
        })
}

export function fetchFailure(data) {
    return {
        type: FETCHING_DATA_FAILED,
        data: data,
    }
}

export function sendUserJd(data) {
    return {
        type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
        data: data,
    }
}

export function fetchingJobDescription() {
    return {
        type: FETCHING_JOBS
    }
}
```

This is my 2nd action.

Now,

```
handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var bodyJson = {
            "username": this.state.UserName,
            "password": this.state.password
        }
        this.props.fetchToken(bodyJson);
    }
```

This is from the container will get called on click of login button.

Now, so, how can I call the second action after a successful login request? I also want to dispatch both the actions.

I tried ->

```
export function getLoginDetails(dispatch, bodyjson) {
    generateToken(bodyjson)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200)
                dispatch(sendToken(response.payload))
                dispatch(fetchUserJd(dispatch))
            else
                dispatch(redirectUser(response.status));
        })
}
```

But No luck . Can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an if/else clause with more than one line you must use curly braces.

```js
export function getLoginDetails(dispatch, bodyjson) {
  generateToken(bodyjson)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        dispatch(sendToken(response.payload));
        dispatch(fetchUserJd(dispatch));
      } else {
        dispatch(redirectUser(response.status));
      }
    })
}
```